# Devel::Cover report Branch and condition Coverage shows n/a in the report ??

Tags: perl, perl-module, cpan, devel-cover

I am generating the coverage for some .pm and mason file using apache by using Devel::Cover
But for the mason file the coverage for branch and condition is showing n/a while for the same mason file statement coverage is coming 100%. Please Help.

Answer (score 2):

Are there any branches and conditions in your mason file?  If not, you will see the n/a.

I presume you are seeing branches and conditions for the pm files, but also check that you haven't turned off branch and condition coverage. They are on by default.

Comment: We have branches and conditions in the mason component and we are not turning off branch and condition coverage. 
We have passed use Devel::Cover in mod_perl file which is included in apache conf.
In apache.conf file we have set PerlSetEnv DEVEL_COVER_OPTIONS -db,<path to cover_db>,-coverage,statement,branch,condition,subroutine